# Is there free software that can be used to generate a chain rule tree graph?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, math-software

I'm in multivariate calculus and we just finished up the chain rule. One of the methods for solving this is to produce a tree graph and traverse it. An example would be this tree graph taken from my notes in class.

[image: Example tree graph]

As part of class we need to write a report and I will be typing it all out in Word. I want to be able to insert tables like this into my report. To do that I need to generate them somehow, where the output could be inserted into Word (an image most likely).

I am wondering if there is any free software that will allow me to generate a tree just as nice as the example that is relatively painless to use. Preferably most of the layout will be managed for me, I'd just need to define the number of nodes, names of the nodes, and the labels of the lines. The software doesn't need to take in equation input, I'm fine with having to name everything manually. I don't need to be able to show different colored lines to show transversal.

I also have access to Maple at my school labs and Mathematica Pi Edition on my Raspberry Pis. If there are no free tools to do this, is it possible to set up in either of them?

Another example, though less desirable, would be this example taken from [Paul's Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChainRule.aspx).

[image: Example tree graph that is less desireable]

Comment: If you're familiar with latex you can use the tikz package - if you have a few specific figures you want I would be happy to help you out if you don't know how to use it

Comment: I've dabbled a little bit in LaTex, but I've only dealt with snippets. If I wanted to make a fully formed document I wouldn't know how to start it. If for example I wanted to remake the graph in the first example how would I go about doing that.

Comment: Creating an example now - will post when I finish (~ 5 min maybe?)

Comment: Ok, don't worry too much about it. I have to turn it in before winter break (in December).

Comment: Heh, took me a bit longer (decided to learn some tex along the way myself) but I'll post soon here, just adjusting colors now.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is somewhat jenky (it's my first really *big* figure created with latex) but I think it *could* get the job done - if you have other specific chains I can create them for you, if you want a more in depth explanation of the code let me know, otherwise I tried to be verbose. Here's the output:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\chainx}{0}
\newcommand{\chainy}{0}
\def\chainleft{(-1)}
\def\chainright{1}
\def\chainup{1}
\def\chaindown{(-1)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\movechainxy}[4]{%
\g@addto@macro\chainx{ + #3 * #2 * cos(#1)}
\g@addto@macro\chainy{ + #4 * #2 * sin(#1)}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\setchainxy}[2]{%
\renewcommand{\chainx}{#1}
\renewcommand{\chainy}{#2}
}
\newcommand{\chainlegs}[7]{%
\draw[#3, very thick] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) -- ({\chainx - 2 * cos(#1)}, {\chainy - #2 * sin(#1)});
\draw[#4, very thick] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) -- ({\chainx + 2 * cos(#1)}, {\chainy - #2 * sin(#1)});
\draw[fill, #6] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) circle [radius=2pt];
\node[#5, #6] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {#7};
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \chainlegs{30}{2}{RubineRed}{RubineRed}{above}{RubineRed}{$z$}
    \movechainxy{30}{2}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \chainlegs{60}{2}{RubineRed}{gray}{left}{ProcessBlue}{$x$}

    \setchainxy{0}{0}
    \movechainxy{30}{2}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \chainlegs{60}{2}{RubineRed}{gray}{right}{ProcessBlue}{$y$}

    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \draw[fill, SeaGreen] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) circle [radius=2pt];
    \node[below, SeaGreen] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$s$};

    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainright}{\chainup}
    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \draw[fill, SeaGreen] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) circle [radius=2pt];
    \node[below, SeaGreen] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$t$};

    \setchainxy{0}{0}
    \movechainxy{30}{2}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \draw[fill, SeaGreen] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) circle [radius=2pt];
    \node[below, SeaGreen] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$s$};

    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainright}{\chainup}
    \movechainxy{60}{2}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \draw[fill, SeaGreen] ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) circle [radius=2pt];
    \node[below, SeaGreen] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$t$};

    \setchainxy{0}{0}
    \movechainxy{30}{1}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \node[above left] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$};
    \movechainxy{30}{1}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}

    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \node[left] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$};
    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainright}{\chainup}
    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \node[right] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$};

    \setchainxy{0}{0}
    \movechainxy{30}{1}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \node[above right] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$};
    \movechainxy{30}{1}{\chainright}{\chaindown}

    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainleft}{\chaindown}
    \node[left] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$};
    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainright}{\chainup}
    \movechainxy{60}{1}{\chainright}{\chaindown}
    \node[right] at ({\chainx}, {\chainy}) {$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I understand it enough. I'll try my own chain tomorrow and then ask for more clarifications. Thanks so much!

Comment: Looking at the colors used and general layout, I wouldn't be surprised if they did something very similar while publishing the book.

Comment: @CupricWolf possibly, no idea though